# Creating spherical inclusions in a cubical matrix using abaqus and python

Tags: python, computational-geometry, abaqus

I have been trying to create spherical clusters in a cube matrix in abaqus using python scripting interface. The code which i wrote works fine, but now i am trying to make larger clusters but i ran out out of ideas on how to do it. Can any one point me in a direction which i could work on. 
**The main idea is to create small clusters by patterns and then combine them to make bigger**

My code is a follows:

```
from part import * # for creating and accessing the part module of abaqus
from material import * # for creating material databases and assigning it to the parts
from section import * # for section properties
from assembly import * # for assembling different parts with sections
from job import * # for setting up the simulation
from sketch import * # for sketching plane sketches
from visualization import * # for rendering and then for various pan and rotate options
from connectorBehavior import *
import random # for creating random coordinates for the centers of the spheres
import math

#Euclidean Distance Measure: this is to measure the distance between sphere, so that they donot collide with each other.
def distance(x, y):
    if len(x) != len(y):
        raise ValueError, "vectors must be same length"
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        sum += (x[i]-y[i])**2
    return math.sqrt(sum)
# To check the sphere Position in the cube and then to determine which direction to have the linear pattern
def  sphere_postion_check(sphList):
    x=[]
    for k in range(len(sphList)):
        sphList[i]=sphList[i]+3*r
        if sphList[i]>1:
            x.append(0.0)
        else:
            x.append(1.0)
    return(tuple(x))
# the above function should be still implemented in the code....            



#Create Cube: First the cube is created by a plane sketch and then extruded in the 3rd direction
mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=200.0) # this will create the 2d planar sheet for sketching
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].rectangle(point1=(0.0, 0.0), point2=(10.0, 10.0)) # sketching is done
mdb.models['Model-1'].Part(dimensionality=THREE_D, name='Part-1', type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)# making it 3d
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].BaseSolidExtrude(depth=10.0, sketch=mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__']) #extruding based on the depth value and making it a solid
del mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__']# delete the sketch


ixt=0 
#Instantiate cube : creatig the instance will help in making operations on the cube like cutting and merging
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Instance(dependent=ON, name='tmpCube', part=mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'])
#File Output: for recording the positions of the cube by capturing the centers of the cube
text_file = open("C:\Users\haris\Desktop\CAME_MINE\HIWI\Codes\Temp\Sphere_Positions.txt", "w")

#Number of Spheres
n = 30
text_file.write("Number of Spheres: " + str(n) + "\n")

#Radius of one sphere: is calculated based on the volume fraction here it 2 percent
r = (3*0.40)/(4*math.pi*n)
print r
r = r**(1.0/3.0)
print "Sphere Radius is " + str(r)
text_file.write("Sphere Radius is " + str(r) + "\n")

#Create Sphere : The sphere is created using a semicircle and a construction line to revolve it around the construction line
mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=200.0) #for drawing the sketch ie semi circle
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].ConstructionLine(point1=(0.0, -100.0), point2=(0.0, 100.0)) #construction line for revloving the semi circle
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].FixedConstraint(entity=mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].geometry[2])
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].ArcByCenterEnds(center=(0.0, 0.0), direction=CLOCKWISE, point1=(0.0, -r), point2=(0.0, r))# Generating the arc
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].Line(point1=(0.0, -r), point2=(0.0, r)) #Closing the arc to create semi circle
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].VerticalConstraint(entity=mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].geometry[4])
mdb.models['Model-1'].Part(dimensionality=THREE_D, name='Part-2', type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)# Setting the type and dimensionality of the sketch ie it should be 3d
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-2'].BaseSolidRevolve(angle=360.0, flipRevolveDirection=OFF, sketch=mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'])#Revolving the geometry
del mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'] # delete the sketch 

#List of Spheres
sphereList = [] # list to maintain track of the Spheres using their positions
sphereInstancesList = [] # to maintain track of the instances which will be used to cut and or translate the spheres


#Create n instances of the sphere
#After creating n instances of the sphere we trie to form cluster around each instance of the sphere
for i in range(1, n+1):
    InstanceName = 'Sphere_' + str(i) # creating a name for the instance of the sphere
    print InstanceName
    text_file.write(InstanceName)

    #Maximum tries to distribute sphere
    maxTries = 10000000

    while len(sphereList) < i:
        maxTries -= 1
        if maxTries < 1:
            print "Maximum Distribution tries exceded. Error! Restart the Script!"
            break;

        # Make sure Spheres dont cut cube sides: this will place the spheres well inside the cube so that they does'nt touch the sides of the cube 
        # This is done to avoid the periodic boundary condition: later in the next versions it will be used
        vecPosition = [(2*r)+(random.random()*(10.0-r-r-r)),(2*r)+(random.random()*(10.0-r-r-r)),(2*r)+(random.random()*(10.0-r-r-r))]
        for pos in sphereList:
            if distance(pos, vecPosition) < 2*r: # checking whether the spheres collide or not
                break
        else:
            sphereList.append(vecPosition)
            print vecPosition
            text_file.write("\t" + str(vecPosition) + "\n")
            #Instantiate Sphere: we have to instatiate the sphere so that it can be used to translate and then used for cuttuing the holes
            mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Instance(dependent=ON, name=InstanceName, part=mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-2'])
            #Translate Instance of Sphere: the sphere instance is translated to the vecPosition genrated above
            mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.translate(instanceList=(InstanceName, ), vector=vecPosition) #translate the sphere created initially: just to duplicate
            sphereInstancesList.append(mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances[InstanceName])# adding the instances to a list to keep track of them
            print sphereInstancesList

print "Sphere Radius is " + str(r)

del mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['tmpCube']

text_file.close()

#Now we create patterns for the created sphere so that we get the clusters: At present we are using the hexagonal clustering: Later we are gonna imporve for making the cluster better
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Instance(dependent=ON, name='tmpCube2', part=mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'])

# we get the names of the instances and then we suppress all of them
instance_list_after=mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances.keys()

for i in range(len(instance_list_after)):
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.features[instance_list_after[i]].suppress()
# now we resume the spheres one by one and then create first a linear pattern and then a radial instance pattern
cluster_Size=[3,4,6,8,10,12,14] #list to give the random number of spheres which forms a cluster
for i in range(1,n+1):
    Number_of_Spheres_Clustered=random.choice(cluster_Size) #selecting randomly from the list cluster_Size
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.features['Sphere_'+str(i)].resume()
    a1 = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
    if Number_of_Spheres_Clustered==3: #for creating a triangular cluster
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=2*r, spacing2=2*r)
        a1.RadialInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i)+'-lin-2-1', ), point=(sphereList[i-1][0],sphereList[i-1][1],sphereList[i-1][2]), axis=(0.0, -1.0, 0.0), number=3, totalAngle=360.0)
    #dir=sphere_postion_check(sphereList[i-1])
    elif Number_of_Spheres_Clustered==4: #for creating a retangular cluster
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=2*r, spacing2=2*r)
        a1.RadialInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i)+'-lin-2-1', ), point=(sphereList[i-1][0],sphereList[i-1][1],sphereList[i-1][2]), axis=(0.0, -1.0, 0.0), number=4, totalAngle=360.0)
    elif Number_of_Spheres_Clustered==6: #for creating a hexoganal cluster
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=2*r, spacing2=2*r)
        # the below code creates the hexoganal symmetric cluster of the linear pattern created above
        a1.RadialInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i)+'-lin-2-1', ), point=(sphereList[i-1][0],sphereList[i-1][1],sphereList[i-1][2]), axis=(0.0, -1.0, 0.0), number=6, totalAngle=360.0)
    elif Number_of_Spheres_Clustered==8:
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=2*r, spacing2=2*r)
        # the below code creates the hexoganal symmetric cluster of the linear pattern created above
        a1.RadialInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i)+'-lin-2-1', ), point=(sphereList[i-1][0],sphereList[i-1][1],sphereList[i-1][2]), axis=(0.0, -1.0, 0.0), number=6, totalAngle=360.0)
        #creates two more spheres after the hexoganl pattern and then adds 2 spheres at the boundaries of the hex pattern
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=4*r, spacing2=4*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(-1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=4*r, spacing2=4*r)
    elif Number_of_Spheres_Clustered==10:
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=2*r, spacing2=2*r)
        # the below code creates the hexoganal symmetric cluster of the linear pattern created above
        a1.RadialInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i)+'-lin-2-1', ), point=(sphereList[i-1][0],sphereList[i-1][1],sphereList[i-1][2]), axis=(0.0, -1.0, 0.0), number=6, totalAngle=360.0)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=4*r, spacing2=4*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(-1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=4*r, spacing2=4*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=6*r, spacing2=6*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(-1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=6*r, spacing2=6*r)
    elif Number_of_Spheres_Clustered==12:
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=2*r, spacing2=2*r)
        # the below code creates the hexoganal symmetric cluster of the linear pattern created above
        a1.RadialInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i)+'-lin-2-1', ), point=(sphereList[i-1][0],sphereList[i-1][1],sphereList[i-1][2]), axis=(0.0, -1.0, 0.0), number=6, totalAngle=360.0)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=4*r, spacing2=4*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(-1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=4*r, spacing2=4*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=6*r, spacing2=6*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(-1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=6*r, spacing2=6*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=8*r, spacing2=8*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(-1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=8*r, spacing2=8*r)
    elif Number_of_Spheres_Clustered==14:
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=2*r, spacing2=2*r)
        # the below code creates the hexoganal symmetric cluster of the linear pattern created above
        a1.RadialInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i)+'-lin-2-1', ), point=(sphereList[i-1][0],sphereList[i-1][1],sphereList[i-1][2]), axis=(0.0, -1.0, 0.0), number=6, totalAngle=360.0)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=4*r, spacing2=4*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(-1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=4*r, spacing2=4*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=6*r, spacing2=6*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(-1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=6*r, spacing2=6*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=8*r, spacing2=8*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(-1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=8*r, spacing2=8*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=10*r, spacing2=10*r)
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(-1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=10*r, spacing2=10*r)

    else:
        # the below code creates the linear instance pattern for a particular sphere
        a1.LinearInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i), ), direction1=(1.0,0.0,0.0), direction2=(0.0,1.0,0.0), number1=2, number2=1, spacing1=2*r, spacing2=2*r)
        # the below code creates the hexoganal symmetric cluster of the linear pattern created above
        a1.RadialInstancePattern(instanceList=('Sphere_'+str(i)+'-lin-2-1', ), point=(sphereList[i-1][0],sphereList[i-1][1],sphereList[i-1][2]), axis=(0.0, -1.0, 0.0), number=6, totalAngle=360.0)
    instance_list_after=mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances.keys()
    # again we supress all
    for j in range(len(instance_list_after)):
        mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.features[instance_list_after[j]].suppress()
    sphereInstancesList_2=[] #keep track of the new instances created
    for k in range(len(instance_list_after)):
        sphereInstancesList_2.append(mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances[instance_list_after[k]])
#after creating the pattern instances for all the initial spheres created we try to cut them: we remove the tmpcube2 from the instance list and then cut the spheres 
print '*****************************************'

sphereInstancesList_cut=[]
for a in range(len(sphereInstancesList_2)):
    if sphereInstancesList_2[a]!=mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['tmpCube2']:
        sphereInstancesList_cut.append(sphereInstancesList_2[a])
print sphereInstancesList_cut

for i in range(len(instance_list_after)):
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.features[instance_list_after[i]].resume()
#cutting the cube instance from the sphere clusters and then creating the part from it  
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.PartFromBooleanCut(cuttingInstances=(sphereInstancesList_cut),
instanceToBeCut=mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['tmpCube2'],name='Part-4')

#Intantiate Cut Object: after cutting the instances from the cube we need to make the part
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Instance(dependent=ON, name='Cube',part=mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-4'])
```

The output of this code looks like this:
[image]

I want to achieve this RVE below:

[image: I want to achieve this RVE:]

Comment: Outch, eight `from ... import *` statements...

Comment: well the code has lot to do  as it has many operations which are to be followed, i just imported all the functions because it would be easy...the code which i posted is a small snippet so many of the import statements will not be necessary..

Comment: I believe this will fail one day if you use `from ... import *` for eight modules. Think about shortnames, e.g. `import mymodule as mm; mm.func()` instead of `from mymodule import *; func()`

Comment: yeah sure i will do that, yes that would be a problem later, already it takes a lot of time now to create that..

Comment: @linusg all of those imports set up a "standard" abaqus/cae/python environment. It would be in my opinion way to cumbersome to tag every symbol in the code with a module reference. (not to mention if you want to use documented example code you would need to change every single symbol ).

Comment: @ayaan you don't say anything about what goes wrong. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @agentp Hi well my main problem was randomizing the cluster formation. So i thought to do it by using patterns option to create small clusters and then to combine small clusters to make bigger clusters. I added another picture to show what i want to achieve.

Comment: @agentp No need to achieve 100 percent of result (of photo which i added). The main problem which i face is when i try to move the cluster towards another cluster by translate command, sometimes it works but sometimes it collides or overlaps with another cluster, which should not happen.

Comment: you might want to add the `computational-geometry` tag.

Comment: You can first run Monte-Carlo simulation with random walking particles and export the coordinates of each particle to your python script

Comment: @gdlmx Hi thanks for that i am trying that. i read in a paper about self avoiding random walk. I will try to code it or will use the existing code, may subprocess it in my code and then i can get coordinates.

Comment: @agentp Hi i added it..